# neo4j optimize read query performance

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need help in optimizing a read query, it becomes very slow(around 3 secs) when the active users go around 250, with less load it takes only a few ms. Our graph size is 435 MB we are running it on a neo4j 3.5 cluster with 16 GB ram.

Query:

```
MATCH (lesson:Mlo)-[MLO_TO_CONTENT]->(Content)-[CONTENT_TO_SKILL]->(skill:Skill)<-[OUTCOME_TO_SKILL]-(outcome:Outcome)
WHERE lesson.mloUuid IN ["uuid-1", "uuid-2"]
AND outcome.boardId = lesson.boardId
AND outcome.gradeId = lesson.gradeId
AND outcome.subjectId = lesson.subjectId
AND exists(skill.name)
AND exists(skill.uuid)
AND exists(outcome.outcomeKey)
RETURN lesson.mloUuid as lessonUuid, skill.name as skillName, skill.uuid as skillUuid, collect(distinct outcome.outcomeKey) as outcomes
```

Configs:

```
Heap 6144 MB
Page Cache 5293 MB
```

:sysinfo

```
Page Cache
Faults    7348
Evictions    0
File Mappings    2544
Bytes Read    58851674
Flushes    9140
Eviction Exceptions    0
File Unmappings    2516
Bytes Written    280641246
Hit Ratio    100.00%
Usage Ratio    1.10%
```

Profile:

[image]

Comment: what indexes are present in your database?

Comment: Add this keyword:  PROFILE on the first line of your query and give the result to us. Thanks.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor mloUuid,  outcomeKey, Skill(name, uuid)

Comment: @jose_bacoy added profile result in the question. Thanks.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly you are missing the : in the relationship labels.

Answer (score 0):

You can try profiling this:

```
MATCH (lesson:Mlo)-[MLO_TO_CONTENT]->(content)-[CONTENT_TO_SKILL]->(skill)<-[OUTCOME_TO_SKILL]-(outcome)
WHERE lesson.mloUuid IN ["uuid-1", "uuid-2"]
AND skill.name IS NOT NULL
AND skill.uuid IS NOT NULL
AND outcome.outcomeKey IS NOT NULL
AND outcome.boardId = lesson.boardId
AND outcome.gradeId = lesson.gradeId
AND outcome.subjectId = lesson.subjectId
RETURN lesson.mloUuid as lessonUuid, skill.name as skillName, skill.uuid as skillUuid, collect(distinct outcome.outcomeKey) as outcomes
```

In this query, we have removed label matches for `skill` and `outcome` nodes. They were taking around 50k DB hits, in the profile graph. However, if there is some mismatch in the response, you should re-add them back. Also, we have updated `exists()` check with `IS NOT NULL`, so that more indexes come into play. You can read more about it [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/indexes/#administration-indexes-existence-check-using-is-not-null-single-property-index).

Another potential option is to provide a `JOIN` hint in the query. These hints basically tell the query planner, how to traverse paths with respect to some particular nodes, so that the cost of traversal is minimized. Try the below query, we have provided the hint using the clause `USING JOIN ON`, any node can follow the clause, I have used `skill` nodes, but you can use `lesson`, `content`, or `outcome` as well, and compare the query response times.

```
PROFILE MATCH (lesson:Mlo)-[MLO_TO_CONTENT]->(content)-[CONTENT_TO_SKILL]->(skill:Skill)<-[OUTCOME_TO_SKILL]-(outcome:Outcome)
USING JOIN ON skill
WHERE lesson.mloUuid IN ["uuid-1", "uuid-2"]
AND outcome.boardId = lesson.boardId
AND outcome.gradeId = lesson.gradeId
AND outcome.subjectId = lesson.subjectId
AND skill.name IS NOT NULL
AND skill.uuid IS NOT NULL
AND outcome.outcomeKey IS NOT NULL
RETURN lesson.mloUuid as lessonUuid, skill.name as skillName, skill.uuid as skillUuid, collect(distinct outcome.outcomeKey) as outcomes
```

You can read more about the planner hint [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-to-avoid-costly-traversals-with-join-hints/).

Comment: thanks @CharchitKapoor, but it doesn't bring improvement in query execution time.

Comment: Ok, is it possible for you to share some data, so that I can try it locally, if it's not sensitive?